# Webview not loaging url

Tags: android, webview

I am simply tring to load url in my web view but its not getting load ,it simply showing me white screen but the same url works well when i hit it on web.
here is my code to load url in webview :-

```html
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
  content = bundle.getString("content");
  url = bundle.getString("url");
  mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_fragment, container, false);
  mTextView = (TextView) mRootView
    .findViewById(R.id.txt_content_discription);
  mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
  WebView mWebView = (WebView) mRootView
    .findViewById(R.id.webView_empty_fragment);
  WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
  settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.loadUrl(url);

  return mRootView;
 }

 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
    SslError error) {
   super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
   handler.proceed();
  }
 }
```

Here is my xml :-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_content_discription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange_color"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView_empty_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: did u give permissions in manifest .. once check the permissions to access wifi

Comment: yes . i have given the permission for internet .

Comment: @demodemo did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Android does not support viewing `PDF`  in a `WebView`.

WebView does not contain a PDF plugin that allow you to display a PDF document.

Luckily, Google allows you to perform this very task quite easily using `Google Docs`.

Try like this:

```
String pdf_url = "http://skyjack.com/sites/default/files/warranty.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf_url);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have load that url it is loading in webview

Comment: yes its getting loaded but second one is not getting  load in webview

Comment: I have tried both url and it is loaded successfully. try with second url if there is any problem in it

Answer (score 2):

```
url= "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+myUrl+"&embedded=true";

webview.loadUrl(url);
```

in myurl specify your url.

The url with .pdf extension you have to open in google doc.
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I already answered the same type of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306165/3983054). You can check it.

In addition to the @Rajesh Jadhav answer, if your drive having a login session you may need to provide the session access as well.

But If you use the view only url the user is not propted to login to there google account.

So in your second url case, simply you can use like this::

```
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+ pdfURL);
```

Here pdf url vll be your tentative url which your trying to load

Still your facing the problem, then you have to follow the link below and setup content access either as Anyone with the link or Public web access, please be reminded that the URL would be something else as well.

[Change your sharing settings](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

The Webview does not show .pdf-files. If you want to show pdf u have to download it and open in a pdfviewer, for example adobe acrobat. u can send a broadcastintent to let the user select the application with which he wants to open the file.